# Скрыть panel если курсор за ее пределами

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

`Panel1` открывается по нажатию на `button`. Нужно чтобы `panel1` скрылась когда курсор выходит за ее границы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У `Panel` есть событие `MouseLeave`. Его и используйте:

```
private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: На панели есть компоненты. Если на них навести курсор, то панель исчезает. Можно как-то сделать чтобы так не было?